OCI Access Tokens (docker, containers)
Where is the OCI spec that defines the GET /token endpoint?
I'm trying to understand more about this command
curl -so "token.json" "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:library/hitch:pull";

I've seen many guides for interacting with the docker API (or other OCI-compliant registry like GitHub Packages) have some variation of this as their first step. Here's another example for GitHub Packages:
curl -so "token.json" "https://ghcr.io/token?service=ghcr.io&scope=repository:homebrew/core/go:pull";

Specifically, I want to understand what is the syntax of the scope GET variable. Generally, I want to read the entire spec about this /token API endpoint.
I read the OCI "distribution spec". At the time of writing, the latest "distribution spec" can be downloaded here:

https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/releases/tag/v1.1.0
https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/releases/download/v1.1.0/oci-distribution-spec-v1.1.0.pdf

The above PDF file defines a set of API endpoints that we can use to query, parse, and then figure out how to download a file from a container registry. The table from the above PDF is copied below:



ID
Method
API Endpoint
Success
Failure




end-1
GET
/v2/
200
404/401


end-2
GET / HEAD
/v2/<name>/blobs/<digest>
200
404


end-3
GET / HEAD
/v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>
200
404


end-4a
POST
/v2/<name>/blobs/uploads/
202
404


end-4b
POST
/v2/<name>/blobs/uploads/?digest=<digest>
201/202
404/400


end-5
PATCH
/v2/<name>/blobs/uploads/<reference>
202
404/416


end-6
PUT
/v2/<name>/blobs/uploads/<reference>?digest=<digest>
201
404/400


end-7
PUT
/v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>
201
404


end-8a
GET
/v2/<name>/tags/list
200
404


end-8b
GET
/v2/<name>/tags/list?n=<integer>&last=<integer>
200
404


end-9
DELETE
/v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>
202
404/400/405


end-10
DELETE
/v2/<name>/blobs/<digest>
202
404/405


end-11
POST
/v2/<name>/blobs/uploads/?mount=<digest>&from=<other_name>
201
404


end-12a
GET
/v2/<name>/referrers/<digest>
200
404/400


end-12b
GET
/v2/<name>/referrers/<digest>?artifactType=<artifactType>
200
404/400


end-13
GET
/v2/<name>/blobs/uploads/<reference>
204
404



Surprisingly, the very first endpoint that you must call in order to call any of the others is missing! And I couldn't find any reference to it in the entire document.
Where can I find the OCI documentation for the GET /token endpoint?

The OCI manual that you're looking for does not exist.
There is a feature request to add it here:

https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/issues/240

In the meantime, see docker's Token Scope Documentation.

https://distribution.github.io/distribution/spec/auth/scope/

Further Reading
This answer was copied from this article on Manually Downloading Container Images (Docker, Github Packages)
